# Abrir paginas no content?

Tags: ionic

Estou usando AngularJS e Ionic para criação de aplicativos hibridos e estou com uma duvida. Criei um projeto com template blank, no index.html veio criado a tag `ion-content` que acredito eh onde renderiza as outras paginas. O problema eh que não estou conseguindo fazer essas outras paginas abrir nesse content. No meu caso eu quero abrir as paginas `main.html` e `login.html` no `<ion-content name="mainContent">`.

Como fazer isso ?

estou tentando assim.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainCtrl.js"></script>

    <!--directives-->



  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">>

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Page</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>

      <ion-content class="padding" name="mainContent">         
      </ion-content>

    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider

  .state('main', {    
    url: "/main",
    replace:true,
    views:{
      'mainContent':{
        templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
      }
    },    
    controller: 'MainCtrl',    
  })

  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'mainContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
});
```

**main.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-pane>
        <div class="principal">
              <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="loginFacebook();">
                  Login by Facebook
              </button>
               <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="goTo('templates/login.html');">
                  Login
              </button>
               <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="goTo('templates/login.html');">
                  Add Login
              </button>
              <a href="#/login">Go to login</a>
        </div>
    </ion-pane> 
</ion-content>
```

**login.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-pane>
    <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.username">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
        </label>
    </div>
    <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
  </ion-pane>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Tente utilizar o `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>`

Comment: Minha resposta responde sua pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Ionic utiliza o [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) para navegar entre states. States são geralmente compostos de um view (template html) e um controller (js).

Há várias maneiras de navegar entre states, por exemplo usando `ui-sref=` ao invés de `href=`. Ou programaticamente (nos controllers) injetando `$state` no controller e chamando `$state.go('myState')`

Você pode definir o state padrão em tempo de configuração, assim:

```
angular.module('App', [ 'ionic' ])
        .config(function ($stateProvider) {

                          $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/myState');
                          ...
})
```

Dito isso, não se trata de carregar html dentro do `<ion-content>`, mas sim de navegar entre states, sendo que o ionic e o ui-router manipulam sua página HTML automaticamente para efetivar a navegação.

Trata-se de uma app SPA (Simple Page App) sendo que vários templates HTML são carregados na página única e são escondidos ou mostrados conforme se navega entre os estados.